# Disable ConvertBack() on TwoWay binding when using UpdateSource()

Tags: silverlight, binding

I am maintaining a SilverLight app, and I had to resort to manually rebind some TextBoxes' text.

So i use:

```
myTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```

Problem is, to do that my TextBox needs to have TwoWay binding, so i set it.
That control uses an unorthodox IValueConverter, that should never do a ConvertBack, but since I got a TwoWay binding... it gets called.

Is there a way to disable ConvertBack(), and yet let Convert() do its job?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Please post your Xaml and whatever code you can so we can provide a practical (and tested) fix.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a converter that handle both directions...

Subclass the existing converter and have the ConvertBack hide the existing one (and return something harmless) while the Convert just calls base.Convert.

Comment: The IValueConverter converts a string into an integer in 7 to 21 range.
So ConvertBack is not an option.

Comment: So the ConvertBack of the subclass should just return the string unchanged.

Comment: ConvertBack gets the integer from the TextBox as parameter, it doesn't have the string, it should convert that int to the string, but that is not possible.

Comment: Are you seriously telling me you can't convert an int to a string? :) Try returning value.ToString() on the value passed to the converter. If you mean something else, please explain or post your code & XAML

Answer (score 0):

The [correct way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convertback.aspx) is to return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` in `ConvertBack`